# What is the best practice to ensure that future UPDATES of rdf are efficient/faster

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I'd like to describe around 50,000 (or probably more) documents. I used Jena to create a default model and started adding resources and the corresponding properties. I haven't done triple store or used Jena's TDB dataset. What is the best practice to ensure that future queries and most importantly UPDATES are much efficient/faster. Someone suggested naming each graph and/or separating them in different files.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions on best practice are generally off topic on SO, you may have better luck asking on an external site like answers.semanticweb.com which has a more liberal policy on questions of this nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more data than is conveniently stored in memory, use an RDF database.  Many files on disk is unlikely to be as efficient.

Either use an in-process database, like Apache Jena TDB, or shared an RDF database server (Jena Fuseki).

A separate server means you can use whatever SPARQL compliant system you want for that.